# LibGDX Collision detection improvements

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision

I'm looking to improve my collision detection algorithm. I am using LibGDX, without Box2D. My problem is that when there are too many entities on my screen the fps drops to like 15.

Here is currently what I have, I am checking for every object on the map, and I am trying to lower the amount of objects every entity check.

```
private static void tileCollision(Entity entity) {

    MapObjects objects = GameScreen.map.getLayers().get(Consts.COLLISION_LAYER_ID).getObjects();

    Vector2 currPos = new Vector2(entity.getPosition().x, entity.getPosition().y);

    for (RectangleMapObject rectangleObject : objects.getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {

        Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObject.getRectangle();

        if (Intersector.overlaps(rectangle, entity.getPosition())) {

            entity.setX(entity.getPrePosition().x);
            if (Intersector.overlaps(rectangle, entity.getPosition())) {
                entity.setX(currPos.x);
                entity.setY(entity.getPrePosition().y);

                if (Intersector.overlaps(rectangle, entity.getPosition())) {
                    entity.setX(entity.getPrePosition().x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the fps drop is being caused by this part of code? I don't know how many objects you already have but Intersector/Rectangle `overlaps` method seems to be rather fast one - also there are no included loops so your alghoritm is about `O(n)`. I would suspect some drawing/asset handling issues at the first place (batch refresh, unnecessary disposing etc...)

Comment: the best way is to make the entity itself check the collision around it only when it moves, don't check every tile that checks every entity every frame, you're doing a lot of heavy math stuff. If your goal isn't study how things works under the hood i really recommend box2d as it's very light, easy to use and you don't need to worry much how some things work (You don't check how bytes are sent or how it works when you send a http request, do you?)